# Как импортировать библиотеку в консоли браузера?

Tags: google-chrome

Нужно импортировать библиотеку для консоли браузера, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

в консоли

`(function(d,s){s=d.createElement('script');s.src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';(d.head||d.documentElement).appendChild(s)})(document);`